# What is the opposite of LoginRequiredMixin, How deny the access to a logged in user?

Tags: python, django

For example, if I don't want to give access to the "Register" view if the user is already logged in?

I use this at the top of each view, and it works fine:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return super(MyCBV_vw, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But maybe there is a decorator o mixin for this, I would like to know if there is a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using class based views, so, I had to used a mixin:

```
class NotLoggedAllow(UserPassesTestMixin):
    login_url = '/profile/'

    def test_func(self):
        return not self.request.user.is_authenticated()

class Register_vw(NotLoggedAllow, FormView):
```

This way I just have to add the name of my mixin at each view, and it does deny the access to a logged in users. Nailed @Moses Koledoye, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Django has a [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test%60) decorator which I think is what you need. The decorator takes a function (with other optional ones) as argument.

You can write this function to redirect all logged in users who are trying to access that view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def not_logged_in(user):
    return not user.is_authenticated()

@user_passes_test(not_logged_in)
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
     # your code
```

Remember to use a [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) to apply this decorator to your `get` method.

Comment: I saw it at the documentation, but it didn't get it, I will read it again slower. I will let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom '`LogoutRequiredMixin`':

```
class LogoutRequiredMixin(View):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return super(LogoutRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then use it in your views:

```
class RegisterView(LogoutRequiredMixin):

    def get(...):
        ...
```

Comment: That mixin should be in the same file (views.py)?
Looks like a good idea. But, is this the way you do this task? Am I doing something rare? I thought that "deny a view access" should be a common task

Comment: That mixin could live wherever you want in your app, you just need import it, I should do it in that way.